# Exception when starting Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

When starting Tomcat I get this exception.

Other than that, Tomcat seems to be running ok.
Still, I don't like exceptions in my console, and my Google searches turned up no relevant results, so help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8787
Handler error
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: startup
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:521)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:464)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:288)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:258)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:256)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:239)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:221)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:973)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:970)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:179)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:156)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:274)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger.getLogger(Jdk14Logger.java:181)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger.<init>(Jdk14Logger.java:61)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.createLogFromClass(LogFactoryImpl.java:1116)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:914)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:604)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:336)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:310)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:60)
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

**Edit**
The contents of server.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
```

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
<Listener className="com.atomikos.tomcat.AtomikosLifecycleListener" />

<GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase" 
        description="User database that can be updated and saved"
        factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
</GlobalNamingResources>

<Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase" />
        </Realm>

        <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" 
                prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
        </Host>
    </Engine>
</Service>
```

*** Edit 2 ***

Here's what I got in the logging.properties file:

```
handlers = startup
.handlers = startup, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

startup.level = FINE
startup.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
startup.prefix = startup.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

Comment: startup seems like a class with non-capital start and in the default package. I'm assuming it's one of yours?

Comment: Please post more configuration details, like server.xml or web.xml.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no class called "startup".

It's doing the same even when I am not deploying any of my apps on it, but it's a modified Tomcat - only I do not know exactly what has been modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since its saying `Handler error` I'm feeling that there is some problem in your tomcat's `conf/logging.properties`.

In particular look for any stray entries in the first two lines of that file. By default these are

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler,
 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

I edited my question to add part of the contents of logging.properties. I suppose the "startup" in there is what's causing the issue, but I wasn't the one who added it and I haven't played with these configs before so I don't know what they're supposed to do.

Comment: Obviously the line `handler = startup` is incorrect and with that line you will always get an exception when you start tomcat as there is no such class with name `startup`. Whoever edited that properties file is clearly doing it wrong. Replace that line with some default entries like the one I mentioned and your server start fine

Comment: Yeap. Did that and the error is gone. I'd still like to find out what the person doing that intended to do - if only I could find whoever did that. Anyway, thanks for the help. I had looked in the other config files, but for some reason I didn't think of looking in logging.properties.